# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #sub_account1 option[value=HD&NO]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP script that queries a DB and returns json_encoded data to a javascript/jquery file that processes the returned data into dynamic options in a drop-down select box.

This has been working fine.  A recently added ampersand, '&', into a field in our database: ereqs.sub_account_code -> 'HD&NO' is causing a syntax error viewed via FireBug when loading the page. When this value is returned by the query below, a jquery/js error interrupts the response and no values get added to the options in the select box.

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #sub_account1 option[value=HD&NO]

javascript file: (json call)

```
function get_sub_account_codes(instance, code){
  // json call to get sub-account-codes.
  $.getJSON("get-sub-account-codes.html",{code:code}, function(data){
     // empty html drop-down of options that may be showing
     $('#sub_account' + instance).html(''); // .empty()
     $('#sub_account' + instance).val('');
     // build the drop-down options
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $("#sub_account" + instance).append("<option value=\""+value.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE+"\">"+value.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE+"-"+value.SUB_ACCOUNT_NAME+"</option>");         
     });
  });
}
```

get-sub-account-codes.html  PHP code to get data.  Called from js file

```
$data = array();
$dbh = SHA_DB::getConnection('webadmin');
$sql = "select distinct sub_account_code, sub_account_name
      from ereqs.kuali_account_codes 
      where account_code = upper(?) and
            sub_account_code is not null
      order by sub_account_code";
$results = $dbh->queryChecked($sql, array($code));
while($d = $results->fetchRow(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC))
{
    $data[] = $d;
}
# return json encoded string.
print json_encode($data);
```

Removing the ampersand '&' is not a viable option.

Is there a way to check for the & in the PHP file and escape it somehow before it is sent back in the `json_encode($data)`?  Or should this be checked for and changed in the javascript code?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Which line is that error being thrown on? Not just the number - but the line **in your code posted in this question**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the error you need to either wrap the value of the attribute selector in quotes:

```
$('#sub_account1 option[value="HD&NO"]');
```

Or you need to escape the special characters, in this case the `&`, with `\\`:

```
$('#sub_account1 option[value=HD\\&NO]');
```

Comment: Thank you!  It took me awhile to get the javascript syntax down, but it is working.  Appreciate the tip.